# Cannot update the UNIQUE column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a *categories* table like this for my forum:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
   category_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
    UNIQUE (name)
) ENGINE =  MYISAM;
```

As you can see, I set up the `name` column as UNIQUE because I intended to allow users to freely create new categories as they wish when they create new posts.

Now, I am creating the `edit.php page` to enable users to edit their own posts, in which I allow them to change the category of the posts if they wish.

Assume that everything goes smoothly with my **UPDATE** query for the `edit.php` page.

However, The problem arised here is that when the user accesses the edit.php page to update the his own post's category, he immediately changes his mind that he **does not want to change** it anymore. The he clicks the **submit** button. The error occurs saying `Duplicate entry 'x' for key y`. I guessed that the root cause was at the `unique(name)` in the table.

So, should I `remove` the **UNIQUE** type for the `name` column and sacrify the feature of allowing users to create new categories freely?

Or, If I can keep it, *your help for a piece of code* will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why are you adding a new row to the table if the user changes his mind about adding a new category?

Comment: @Barmar: sorry for being unclear, but I dont mean that the user adds the new category for his editing process, but `adding new category name` is for `creating` new posts only. Here, while he changes his mind to **keep** the category name unchanged before clicking the submit button, the problem happens.

Comment: So if he didn't change the category name, why are you trying to insert into the category table? You should only add to the category table when the user tries to create a new category.

Comment: If the user is given a choice between selecting an existing category from a menu, or naming a new category, you need to add a validation check -- confirm that the new category doesn't have the same name as one of the existing categories.

Comment: @Barmar: when the user clicks the `submit` button (edit.php page) without changing the category name (but he really changes the post's title and body text or so), that means he actually performs the `UPDATE` action **(LET'S FORGET ABOUT THE PROCESS OF ADDING NEW CATEGORY NAME IN THE ADD_NEW_POST.PHP PAGE )**. Consequently, the `UPDATE` query runs and the value (`category name) is now logically and technically updated, right? that's why I ask this question.

Comment: If he doesn't add a new category, you should only be updating the category column in the `posts` table, not the `categories` table. `posts.category` shouldn't be unique.

Comment: @Barmar: very good suggestion! recommended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a database problem which you can solve with SQL. This is an application problem. If no category must be changed or added, the application should not try to change or add categories. Removing the UNIQUE attribute would probably allow the application to do an unwanted change, which doesn't seem to me a great solution.

Anyway, I suggest you use InnoDB. MyISAM does not provide any benefit for this kind of tables.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I firstly usd InnoDB, then I changed to MYISAM because I thought that InnoDB is for transaction. Now I switch it back to InnoDB as you adviced as I also thought that I don't need FULLTEXT type here!. Another benefit is that it would serve for my commercial purpose in the future, if any. Thanks a lot!

Comment: MyISAM generally doesn't improve your performance. It can be beneficial for VERY big tables, when you do dataware housing and business intelligence. Also, recent InnoDB versions support fulltext.

Answer (score 0):

Add duplicate validation before update the category this is mandatory

For this case append another condition `name != '$_POST["name"]'` in the update query.

```
UPDATE categories SET name = '$_POST["name"]'
WHERE category_id = '$_POST["category_id"]'
AND name != '$_POST["name"]'
```

Comment: I havent tested this as yet because @Barmer's comment solve my problem. Thanks anyway!